# How to create a dictionary using only the values of another two dictionaries

Tags: python

I need to code a loop that gives me an output that gives me two informations.
The first one should give two numbers. The left number represent the month, while the right number is the first day of its month (e.g. for january, (1,1)).

The second information is the same as the first information, but the number to the right represent the final day of its month (e.g. for february, (2,28)).

So, in short, the output of this loop should work like this, from january to december:

```
(1,1) (1,31)  
(2,1) (2,28)  
(3,1) (3,31)  
(4,1) (4,30)  
.  
.  
.  
(11,1) (11,30)  
(12,1) (12,31)
```

I have tried using dictionaries, to no avail. One of them like this:

```
month = {  
    "jan": 1,  
    "fev": 2,  
    "mar": 3,  
    "abr": 4,  
    "mai": 5,  
    "jun": 6,  
    "jul": 7,  
    "ago": 8,  
    "set": 9,  
    "out": 10,  
    "nov": 11,  
    "dez": 12  
}
```

Comment: The `dict` approach is a good idea. I would suggest modifying it slightly: store the index of the month along with the start and end days together. For example, `"jan": (1, (1, 31))`. If you want to eliminate on redundancy a bit, you can also have it like `"feb": (2, 28)` because the start day is always going to be 1 for any month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from calendar import monthrange
year = 2021  # last day for February is year dependent!

for i in range(12):  # iterate through the months
    m = i+1
    n_days = monthrange(year, i+1)[1]
    print(f'({m},1) ({m}, {n_days})')
```

```
(1,1) (1, 31)
(2,1) (2, 28)
(3,1) (3, 31)
(4,1) (4, 30)
(5,1) (5, 31)
(6,1) (6, 30)
(7,1) (7, 31)
(8,1) (8, 31)
(9,1) (9, 30)
(10,1) (10, 31)
(11,1) (11, 30)
(12,1) (12, 31)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It does exactly what I wanted and even more, because before I had to consider that february always has 28 days.
There is only one part of that code that I didn't understand:
In the second to last line, after the parameters for the method monthrange, why there is a [1]?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html), `calendar.monthrange(year, month)` "returns weekday of first day of the month and number of days in month, for the specified year and month." The `[1]` is because we only need the number of days in the month.